# AutoMapper how to map DTO to entity and then map additional related entity

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have this dto model:

```
public class WorkoutModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public List<ExerciseModel> Exercises { get; set; }
}
```

I have programId in this DTO, and this is how I am saving to db:

```
public async Task<int> CreateAsync(WorkoutModel model, string createdBy)
{
    var workout = _mapper.Map<Workout>(model);
    workout.Program = await _repository.GetByIdAsync<Program>(model.ProgramId);

    _repository.Create(workout, createdBy);
    return await _repository.SaveAsync();
}
```

How do I use automapper instead of ugly:

```
workout.Program = await _repository.GetByIdAsync<Program>(model.ProgramId);
```

which doesn't serve purpose of using automapper only.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/991

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to change your `Workout` entity class. Add `public int ProgramId { get; set; }` property as your `public Program Program { get; set; }` is stored in the database as foreign key to `Program` table and that is represented by convention by `ProgramId` column which will be represented with added property in entity class.

You don't need to load Program entity from database in case you know reference identifier.

Then you just can update your mapping to map `model.ProgramId` to `entity.ProgramId` and omit call to database `workout.Program = await _repository.GetByIdAsync<Program>(model.ProgramId);`